# NullPointer exception In jetty 8 Cookie

Tags: java-7, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

My Application uses cookie to do some operation. Previously my Application was deployed on Jboss and it was working fine. Now we need to migrate the application to jetty-8 Server.and i am getting this exception at run-time. I am pretty Sure it is not the code problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.addCookie(Response.java:150)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDK should be augmented with the jce security policies library : Visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html.

After adding the two jars it started working fine.